# Cisco Packet Tracer: Clear screen (cls) in PC Command Prompt

Tags: packet, cisco-packet-tracer

[image]

I notice that the `cls` and `clear` commands don't work in Cisco Packet Tracer's PC.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No. Just keep pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the file and then re-opened it and it seemed to reset Command Prompt for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I use is a little trick, just select the text you want to clear, drag and drop to the main CPT window (the one where you create your network), i don't know if it works on other versions other than mine thought.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to top menu row to "Extensions"
- Select "Clear Terminal Agents"
  -you will get a a small window with all of the network devices.  Select the device you want to clear.